# $A$ closed subset of a metric space $(M,d)$ , let $r>0$ , then is $X(A,r):=\{x\in M : \exists a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)=r\}$ closed in $M$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $A$ be a closed subset of a metric space $(M,d)$ , let $r>0$ , let

$X(A,r):=\{x\in M : \exists a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)=r\}$ , then is it true that $X(A,r)$ is closed in $M$ ?

I can figure out that $X(A,r)=\cup_{a \in A} S(a;r)$ ; though each $S(a;r)$ is closed in $M$ , we are getting an arbitrary union so we can't conclude anything from this . I was wondering if it is true that $X(A;r)=Bd \{x\in M : dist (x,M)\le r \}$ ... Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, $A=(0,1]$, and $r=1$; then $X(A,r)=(-1,0)\cup(1,2]$, which is not closed in $X$, since it has $1$ as a limit point.