# $A$ closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ , $r>0$ , is $X(A,r):=\{x\in \mathbb R^2 : \exists a\in A $ such that $d(x,a)=r\}$ closed in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $(\mathbb R^2,d)$  , where $d$ is the usual euclidean metric , let $r>0$ , let

$X(A,r):=\{x\in \mathbb R^2 : \exists a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)=r\}$ , then is it true that $X(A,r)$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$ ? Brian Scott's answer here shows that it need not necessarily be true for generic metric spaces  [$A$ closed subset of a metric space $(M,d)$ , let $r>0$ , then is $X(A,r):=\{x\in M : \exists a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)=r\}$ closed in $M$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939672/a-closed-subset-of-a-metric-space-m-d-let-r0-then-is-xa-r-x-i)  , but $\mathbb R^2$ might have a nicer geometry . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: what is $A$, an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Specifically, in $(\Bbb R^2,d)$ all bounded closed sets are compact.

Let $p_n\in X(A,r)$ such that $p_n\to p$. By definition, there is $x_n\in A$ such that $d(x_n,p_n)=r$. Since $p_n$ converges, the set $\{p_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$ is bounded, hence $x_n$ is a bounded sequence. Therefore, there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x$ and, since $A$ is closed, $x\in A$. But, by continuity of $d$, $$d(p,x)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}d\left(p_{n_k},x_{n_k}\right)=r$$

Hence, $p\in X(A,r)$.